# How can I limit REST API response to less than 2000 records?

Tags: rest-api, rest, limits

I have seen several question that ask the opposite, how to overcome that limit. I need smaller response because some downstream issue I have with very long responses. I cannot use the LIMIT clause because that limits the full response but I still need to loop with nextRecordsUrl on the full response. I just need to do it with a longer loop on shorter responses.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? Code samples would also be welcome.

Comment: Please do not edit this question. An Adrian Larson edited my question to have its meaning completely reversed. I had to edit it back.
Weird that questions can be edited by others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Query Options Header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_queryoptions.htm) to adjust the batchSize. You can reduce it down to 200 records. The default is 2,000 records.

Salesforce may reduce the batch size automatically if you select particularly large fields.

> `batchSize`—A numeric value that specifies the number of records returned for a query request. Child objects count toward the number of records for the batch size. For example, in relationship queries, multiple child objects are returned per parent row returned.

Example

```
Sforce-Query-Options: batchSize=1000
```

For reference, the same concept also applies to the SOAP API -- [Change the Batch Size in Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_changing_batch_size.htm).